# I'm getting a SyntaxError when trying to run the ember CLI command

Tags: ember.js, npm, command-line-interface

So I recently installed Ember and I was using the Getting Started guide on their site to work on a tutorial project, but unfortunately, when I tried to run the ember command, it threw this strange error. I have attached the image of the SyntaxError.

I have searched everywhere, but I couldn't find an answer to help resolve my issue. Can anyone help me out on how I can get this to work?

Thank you.[image]

Comment: What's your Node.js version? (Run `node -v` to get it)

Comment: My node version is 0.12.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade your Node.js version to v4 or later (v7 is the latest). You can download Node.js from here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/.

`class` is a new feature that was added to ES6, a new version of Javascript that came out in 2015. Node.js did not support `class` prior to v4; that is why you are getting this error. http://node.green/#ES2015-functions-class